# Can I run socket server in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

In my iOS app, I need to configure a socket server for receiving data from a remote client.

Does anyone have experience in socket programming in iOS?

Any good open source library to use?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can, but you shouldn't if you can use an Async client.

Explain your problem a little more and you might get more ideas from contributors here.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake before. I want to establish a socket server in iOS.

Answer (score 1):

**YES**, you can run a socket client in iOS.

and **YES**, I have experience in socket programming under iOS.

Any other question?

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake before. I want to establish a socket server in iOS.